# regex_split() equivalence in VC++11 using only standard libraries

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11

So, i have a sample file and i'm trying to read it in one line at a time. Based on the first word of the line, i want to determine how to handle the remainder of it.

```
baa made up text
squeak 954823
moo 0 321 123 45543 
.     ^
. more moo lines here, fixed in length
.     v
squeak x
woof 8
oink 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 98 93 12 23 43 
.     
. more oink lines here, m in quantity, differing in length
.
woof x
baa x
//more text here
```

I'm using only  at this moment. I've got several regular expressions meant to deal with these formats of lines. The problem i'm sorting out is how to properly access the subgroup matches in the right sequence. All of the material i've found is referring to GCC as the compiler, and i'm experiencing different behavior with the vc++ compiler. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I want to verify that each line is a match against:

```
^(baa|squeak|moo|woof|oink)\s(.*)
```

This is syntax that I wrote/built in Expresso, which doesn't seem to be quite what VC++ regex is looking for. For now, I'm going to assume it is correct - it does describe the two subgroups I want.

then, let's assume we're looking at the first example line above, and have verified that the first subgroup matches 'baa', i want to check: is the second subgroup only a 'x' or is it comprised of more? if it's comprised of more i'm going to execute a function A() and otherwise i'll execute a function B().

Then, depending on what word the first subgroup matches, I want to handle the second subgroup with a different regex, cutting up different parts of the subgroup further. Unfortunately, it seems as though it isn't entirely linear to iterate through the matches.

In my reading, i encountered a boost::regex function named regex_split() which seems to do what I was looking for, but it's deprecated.

I was looking at the boost::tokenizer functionality as well, and though I can get it to do what I want, the regex method promises to be cleaner.

So, my question, in a single line:

What is the right code to use the regex_iterator() function in visual c++ in Visual Studio 2010 without the Boost libraries in order to split the subgroups as I've described?

Is there any way to use named subgroups(a la Perl) with the standard regex libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Given the triviality of the regex you're dealing with, I'd say the correct way is to not bother with a regex for this job at all. I'd just do something like:

```
std::set permitted{"baa", "squeak", "moo", "woof", "oink"};

std::string head, tail;

while (infile >> head)
    if (permitted.find(head) == permitted.end())
        bad_input(head);
    else
        std::getline(infile, tail);
```

Depending on the situation, you might want to use an `std::map` instead of an `std::set`. That would let you store the regex (and possibly a reference to some code) to match and process the rest of that line.

Comment: Thanks, that helps some. So now i can identify the first word based on those initial words which identify the way the context-sensitive line should be read. But I still need help with the regex_<function>() calls to break the next lines into their pieces, or when I need to process the data i've read so far. Any suggestions would be appreciated!